# extjs datefield iso format?

Tags: extjs, format, datefield

What is the correct format string for an ext date field of the following kind:

2010-06-22T17:00:00

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, it is "c"

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Ext [Date docs](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Date)?  Should be something like: `"Y-m-d\\TH:i:s"`